# Adding Docker support to a ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker

I'm working on adding Docker support to an established asp application that has been working great. I was hoping to leverage VS2017 Docker features and functionality by just hitting "add Docker support" and seeing what that "F5 experience" would be like. As luck would have it I was immediately plagued with errors that are a bit cryptic

```
1>------ Build started: Project: docker-compose, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(80,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolveProjectInputAndOutput" task failed unexpectedly.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(80,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(80,5): error MSB4018: Parameter name: path1
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(80,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(80,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Docker.BuildTasks.ResolveProjectInputAndOutput.ResolveRelativeOutputAssemblyPath(TargetOS targetOS, TargetFramework targetFramework, DockerDevelopmentMode developmentMode)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(80,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Docker.BuildTasks.ResolveProjectInputAndOutput.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(80,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.Docker.targets(80,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I popped over to the file in question and it's specifically an issue here:

```
<Target Name="DockerResolveProjectInputAndOutput">
<ResolveProjectInputAndOutput ProjectDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" DockerComposeProjectPath="$(DockerComposeProjectPath)" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" References="@(Reference)" TargetFileName="$(TargetFileName)" TargetPath="$(TargetPath)" />
</Target>
```

So I took a peak in the proj file to see if there are any Docker specific issues that can be found. I only found one reference here:

```
<DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
```

It seems like some configuration hasn't been properly done and it's causing this issue, but haven't had much luck figuring out what/where it would be.

Comment: This project has a "stepping up process" to add docker support.  Maybe in the "steps" you can find some magic values.       https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopModernizing/wiki/02.-How-to-containerize-the-.NET-Framework-web-apps-with-Windows-Containers-and-Docker

Comment: grandaCoder, thanks for the tip, funnily enough that's what I was using as a baseline to begin with so there weren't enough details there to troubleshoot. It also seems to be presented like much more of a point and click thing than it's turning out to be.

Comment: I hear ya dude.  #aintAsEasyAsTheyWantYouToBelieve

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? Could you possibly answer your own question? It would really help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was this: We had a bunch of configurations (Dev, Test, Beta, Prod, Debug, and Release). But, in the project file of the app I was trying to add container support to we didn't have a `<PropertyGroup>` section for Debug. That section is where the `OutputPath` is.

Oddly, I got the error even when running in the `Dev` config.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Dev\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
```